# Isn't this Layla Heartfilia's grave?

Tags: fairy-tail, fairy-tail-zero

As far as I remember, this is Lucy's mother's grave. Then is the person standing in front of the grave Lucy's brother or is he/she her relative?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is Layla Heartfilia's grave and if I remember correctly, that's [Anna Heartfilia](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Anna_Heartfilia), her ancestor, standing in front of it.

> She was the teacher of the five Dragon Slayers that were sent to the future in order to eradicate Acnologia.

Everything about her will be revealed in the later part of the story.

Comment: Thanks , i think i will be waiting . But which episode of the anime this truth will be revealed ?

Comment: I do not watch the anime but I've read the manga. I think she only appeared on the last arc and during Fairy Tail's final battle (or second to the last major battle)